# Edit String in Crystal Reports - Creating Bullet Points

Tags: database, crystal-reports, report

I have fields that contain line breaks, I want to add a `"-"` after each line break, So it looks like bullet points.

However, some of the entries already have a `dash` at the beginning of each line, while others have a different symbol such as `-->`.

I want to unify each to be `"-"`

Is there a way to do something like:

`If {table.field}`starts with `"-"` after each line break then leave as is

`else if {table.field}` startswith `"-->"` after each line break then change to `"-"`

`else if {table.field}` starts with `""` after each line break then change to `"-"`

To visualize, I want it to be like this:

```
Texttext

-textextext

-textext

While it may currently be like this:

Textext

textext

textext
```

Comment: Are those special characters appended to the fields? Can you give example of those fileds how they are printed?

Comment: It is just meant to be the normal hyphen that is on the keyboard, the arrow is just two hyphens and the > sign.

I'm just looking for the appropriate syntax